# phabricator diffusion git username password for git fetch

Tags: git, phabricator

With a Phabricator server installed, I am trying to add a git private repo to be used in Diffusion and in Differential for code review.
I added a git repo on the Phabricator web console and was able to manually clone the repo on the server. With that am able to browse via diffusion.

But subsequent git fetch as part of the PhabricatorRepositoryPullLocalDaemon fails with

`stderr:fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
error: Could not fetch origin`

I tried following:

I added my credentials that I used to `git clone` to `git config --global list` and can see it in `.gitconfig` file in the user home dir (in this case root)

I also added a `.netrc` file in root home dir containing

```
machine github.com
login <username>
password <password
```

Please let me know what am I missing. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Also did the following: copied .gitconfig and .netrc to /var/www and chown both the files as www-data:www-data so that apache can read both. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it.

saw this in daemon.log

```
COMMAND
HOME='/phabricator/support/empty/' git clone --origin origin 'https://github.com/
```

added to the above HOME dir .gitconfig with username password

Comment: Thank you for sharing this obscure behavior of phabricator! Saved a couple of hours for me.